# How to access an integer that is being stored in a char array?

Tags: c, memory

So I have figured out how to store an integer in a char array which I declared as (char arr[4096] = {'\0'};) by casting one of the indices to an integer pointer, but how do I then access this integer that is being stored in the char array afterwards?

I have tried printing the value as an int but it is not working. Below I will show the initial declaration followed by the attempted print statement.

```
int *metaptr = (int*)(&arr[2]);
*metaptr = numb;
printf("%d\n",&arr[2]);
```

Basically I am expecting numb's value to be printed but instead an address(presumably) is being printed. How can I access the integer value which I have stored in this char array?

Comment: Use a debugger to examine the memory that you are operating on to see if it's working the way that you think. Your insertion of an Int 'works' but it doesn't fit into the character memory space. When you pull it back out for printing you are only pulling out part of what you put in.

Comment: *So I have figured out how to store an integer in a char array which I declared as (char arr[4096] = {'\0'};) by casting one of the indices to an integer pointer*- that is undefined behavior, violating strict aliasing.

Comment: furthermore, `&arr[2]` is not an `int`, but rather a pointer to a `char` (assuming `arr[]` is a `char` array), so even if your aliasing violation were not undefined behavior, you're printing the wrong thing.

Comment: Yeah so how would I pull out the entire int instead of just one byte? @john elemans

Comment: By following the reverse procedure.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons Things like this are by necessity done commonly in systems programming. However, a systems programmer would likely know what hardware they're targeting and whether it can handle misaligned ints, or they'll take steps to ensure proper alignment.

Comment: @CareyGregory There are legal ways of accomplishing this and, to my understanding, a good compiler should be able to recognize these common work-arounds (such as use of memcpy) and optimize them.

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```
printf("%d\n", *metaptr);
```

or this:

```
printf("%d\n", *((int*)(&arr[2])));
```